# Tax form to prove state tax payment

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

My state tax for 2013 turned out to be larger then was withheld. As a result, the extra state tax I paid was included (by Glacier software) into the "Itemized deduction" line of my 2014 federal return. Apparently, the IRS did not believe that I paid this extra state tax, and that I am qualified for that extra deduction: they sent me a notice that they want me to prove it. The same situation is described in [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44762/1040nr-ez-previous-years-paid-state-tax-itemized-deductions).

How do I prove I paid that extra tax? Should I request some form from the state revenue service? Or should I just send to the IRS all 10 pages of my 2013 state tax return?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your State tax return and the bank statement showing the check/deduction for that amount (and the canceled check itself, if you mailed a check).